# Can i link multiple WSO2 API Managers(AM) with a single WSO2 Identity Server(IS)?

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-identity-server

The following link shows how to configure a single AM with the IS.
https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM220/Configuring+WSO2+Identity+Server+as+a+Key+Manager

The parameter `<ServerURL>https://${gateway-server-host}:{port}/services/</ServerURL>` from IS config.xml file defines the AM URL to be associated to it.

I want to link 2 different API managers to the same Identity Server **WITHOUT LOAD BALANCER** because the 2 AMs will be handled by 2 separate teams.

Note: It works with load balancer but that is not my requirement.

Thanks for your time :)

Answer (score 0):

That config is only used to remove gateway cache when user roles etc. updated on IS side. So configuring this to point only a single APIM will have a very minimal effect.

Edit: This might work. Add a new environment for the 2nd APIM node.

```
</Environments>
    <Environment type="production" api-console="true">
        <Name>Production Gateway</Name>
        <Description>Production Gateway Environment</Description>
        <ServerURL>https://localhost:9444/services/</ServerURL>
        <Username>admin</Username>
        <Password>admin</Password>
        <GatewayEndpoint>http://localhost:8281,https://localhost:8244</GatewayEndpoint>
    </Environment>
    <Environment type="hybrid" api-console="true">
        <Name>Production and Sandbox</Name>
        <Description>Hybrid Gateway Environment</Description>
        <ServerURL>https://localhost:9445/services/</ServerURL>
        <Username>admin</Username>
        <Password>admin</Password>
        <GatewayEndpoint>http://localhost:8282,https://localhost:8245</GatewayEndpoint>
    </Environment>
</Environments>
```

Comment: You can't do that, and you don't have to.

Comment: Can you find a solution for this issue? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56679528/login-role-permission-issue-with-secondary-jdbc-user-store-in-wso2-identity-serv/56700403#56700403

Comment: Updated the answer with a possible soliution.